# Обучающая выборка на русском языке для анализа тональности

Tags: нейронные-сети, выборка, машинное-обучение

Есть ли у кого обучающая выборка на русском языке  для анализа тональности? Я смог найти только эту - http://study.mokoron.com . В сумме там около 230 тыс. этого довольно мало для толковой классификации с использованием нейросети. На кинопоиске например есть 636332 классифицированных рецензий, вот только я не смог найти эти данные для скачивания. Не знаю есть ли они вообще в открытом доступе. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Могу подать идею в обмен на код нейросеточки

```
pip install poliglo
from polyglot.text import Text as T
text = T("это очень плохо. А это намного лучше, даже хорошо!")
print(text.polarity)
for s in text.sentences:
    print( s, s.polarity)
```

А сам датасет можно взять из твиттера.
Если установить субд Crate.io. то там есть визард высасывающий твиты в базу.
Просто закачиваешь и потом обрабатываешь этим кодом